# Simple java test library to validate generated tags

Tags: java, validation, junit

I have code that generates snippets of HTML and other markup types. Assuming markup follows XML/HTML notation, can anyone recommend a simple Java library for doing basic validation of generated markup tags. Ensuring tag is well formed, and allows me to test presence and value of attributes etc.

e.g.

TagTester tag = TagTester(stringTag);

assertTrue(tag.hasAttribute("action"));

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on HtmlUnit. You can also use JUnit + any HTML parser (there are a lot) + very simple glue code that parses HTML using the parser and calls asserts of JUnit.

You can use TestNG instead of JUnit if your want.